# Reading multiple .csv.gz files from S3 bucket

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark

Objective : I am trying to accomplish a task to join two large databases (>50GB) from S3 and then write a single output file into an S3 bucket using sagemaker notebook (python 3 kernel).

My Approach :  I was able to use pyspark in sagemaker notebook to read these dataset, join them and paste multiple partitioned files as output on S3 bucket. As a next step, I want to read this partitioned data and append it and paste it as single file. Currently I am trying to use pandas for this purpose but I am unable to read all the files at once. Could anyone guide me with a code to read all files from S3 into single df and write it or any alternate approach to accomplish the objective.

Comment: One alternate approach would be to stick with pyspark and use `repartition` or `coalesce` to write your output in a single file.

Comment: @teedak8s Thanks for the suggestion. I tried using coalition and repartition but keep getting out of memory error. Hence, I was looking for an alternate approach